How to track changes to a multifield record in DB
I have a table that keep records that can be added and then updated by a user. Record has many fields. Some fields can be logically grouped, some have similar or the same data type. I need to keep in the DB all the revisions to this records.
For now I can think of two approaches:

Create new record for each change and connect it with the previous one in some way.
Create as many new tables as there are fields in the record and track change for each field. This likely needs some additional tables to keep common metadata for the revision.

Analysis for the approaches:

Easy to implement. Very efficient if most of the fields get changed between revisions.
If only small number of fields is changed between revisions then provides big memory save.

What would you advise?

You can create a History table that you save the record to BEFORE you run an update.  This history table would have just 2 new fields, an ID and a InsertIntoHistory date.  Then you can compare the current table to the history table by whatever PK is in the main table to the History table and see what fields changed and on what date/time.

@Brad this is basically the first approach.

Sorry I think I read through it too quickly.  I think that is the best approach and you can write whatever analysis/queries to find/generate any reports you need.

Since on SO we deal with objective questions, I will presume for the space of this answer that success means efficient in performance and economic in space usage.
So, you have a table, such as
t(id, c1, c2, ..., cn)

Let's suppose that you further create a t_history table like
t_history(id, t_id, version)

and a t_history_changes table, such as
t_history_changes(id, t_history_id, descriptor, value)

Your descriptor could be a column or a group of columns and the value is the change. So, if you change 10 fields to have a value, then this will create a single t_history_changes for those 10 changes and you identify this in some manner inside the descriptor.
You can also create insert, update and delete triggers which will insert a new t_history record for the record's insert/update/delete and as many t_history_changes records as you need. Of course you could have a special value for version for records that you delete.
These triggers would group the changes and .insert t_history_changes accordingly.
